# Using the mutate function in R to convert numerical months in seasons

Tags: r

bit of an embarrassing newcomer question here.

How do I convert a data from listing months into seasons.

```
winter = c(12, 1, 2), 
spring = c(3, 4, 5)
summer = c(6, 7, 8)
autumn = c(9, 10, 11)
movies.lm <- mutate(movies.lm, thtr_season = if(thtr_rel_month %in% "winter",  "winter"), (thtr_rel_month %in% "spring", "spring"), (thtr_rel_month %in% "summer", "summer"), (thtr_rel_month %in% "autumn", "autumn)
```

This naturally returns a stack of delightful errors.

Anyone know how to do what I'm trying to do here in R?

Comment: As for why this returns a stack of delightful errors: first is `movies.lm` a data.frame? Second, you are using `if` incorrectly. If using `mutate` from dplyr you should look up `case_when` syntax.

Comment: Since you did not post any data, I cannot post a solution. As Alex suggested `case_when` should work. You could also use `recode` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nice natural structure of `ifelse`:

```
months <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,11,12)
movies.lm <- data.frame(months)
movies.lm$season <- ifelse(months==12 | months==1 | months==2, "Winter", 
                           ifelse(months==3 | months==4 | months==5, "Spring", 
                                  ifelse(months==6 | months==7 | months==8, "Summer",
                                         ifelse(months==9 | months==10 | months==11, "Autumn", 
                                                NA)))) 
>movies.lm
   months season
1       1 Winter
2       1 Winter
3       1 Winter
4       2 Winter
5       3 Spring
6       4 Spring
7       5 Spring
8       6 Summer
9       7 Summer
10      8 Summer
11      8 Summer
12      9 Autumn
13     11 Autumn
14     12 Winter
```

`mutant` might be more elegant in some situations, especially when working with big data, however in simple cases I would prefer simple solutions.

Comment: This is terrific, thank you. 

Just curious, how would you do it with the mutate function? I've been trying to get that to work but I'm struggling.

Comment: I guess to be clear movies.lm is an existing data frame with where I'm trying to add a column called "thtr_release_season" which would use thtr_release_month to determine and list which season (using the standard above) the movie was released in. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I tried updating this somewhat to suit my situation and have ended up getting a column filled with empty values. (n/a).

movies.lm <- movies.lm %>% mutate(thtr_season = ifelse("thtr_rel_month" %in% "winter", 12 | "thtr_rel_month"==1 | "thtr_rel_month"==2, "Winter", 
   ifelse("thtr_rel_month"==3 | "thtr_rel_month"==4 | "thtr_rel_month"==5, "Spring", 
          ifelse("thtr_rel_month"==6 |"thtr_rel_month"==7 | "thtr_rel_month"==8, "Summer",
                 ifelse("thtr_rel_month"==9 | "thtr_rel_month"==10 | "thtr_rel_month"==11, "Autumn", 
                        NA)))))

Comment: I don't know the structure of the data set well enough and I am not very used to `mutate()` but I edited my answer so that the code will add the results as a new variable to your data set

Answer (score 0):

Since the seasonal months are contiguous this is a good job for the `cut` function:

```
months <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,11,12)

seasons <- c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn")
indx <- cut(months %% 12, # send 12 to 0
            seq(0, 12, 3), # cut into three month cycles
            labels = F, # return index
            include.lowest = T, # include lower bounds (0, 3, 6, 9)
            right = F # exclude upper bounds (3, 6, 9, 12)
)

seasons[indx]

# [1] "Winter" "Winter" "Winter" "Winter" "Spring" "Spring" "Spring" "Summer"
# [9] "Summer" "Summer" "Summer" "Autumn" "Autumn" "Winter"
```

`cut` with `labels = F` produces an index which lets you subset the `season` character vector.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

seasons <- c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn")

movies.lm <- data.frame(thtr_rel_month=c(1,7,5,2,12,11,6,3,8,4,5,10,9))

movies.lm <- mutate(movies.lm, thtr_season = seasons[cut((thtr_rel_month%%12)+1, breaks=4)])

movies.lm
#>    thtr_rel_month thtr_season
#> 1               1      Winter
#> 2               7      Summer
#> 3               5      Spring
#> 4               2      Winter
#> 5              12      Winter
#> 6              11      Autumn
#> 7               6      Summer
#> 8               3      Spring
#> 9               8      Summer
#> 10              4      Spring
#> 11              5      Spring
#> 12             10      Autumn
#> 13              9      Autumn
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method using dplyr's mutate:

```
> movies.lm <- data.frame(months = c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,11,12))
> 
> library(dplyr)
> movies.lm <- movies.lm%>%
+   mutate(season = setNames(rep(c('Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter','Spring'),each=3),
+                              c(12,1:11))[as.character(months)])
> 
> movies.lm
   months season
1       1 Summer
2       1 Summer
3       1 Summer
4       2 Summer
5       3 Autumn
6       4 Autumn
7       5 Autumn
8       6 Winter
9       7 Winter
10      8 Winter
11      8 Winter
12      9 Spring
13     11 Spring
14     12 Summer
```